# Can Vulkan/MoltenVK run under armv7s

Tags: arm, vulkan

I've downloaded the MoltenVK, and it seems geared only to arm64.  Can it run under arm7vs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All iPhones that run Metal (A7 onwards) are 64-bit only.